# Escape space character in pathfile?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an environment variable for Anki's media folder, in `.bash_profile`.

The line is `export ANKI_MEDIA='/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Anki2/me/collection.media'`.

Once *sourced*, I try `echo $ANKI_MEDIA` which correctly returns the full path but if I do `cd $ANKI_MEDIA` I get back `-bash: cd: "/Users/<username>/Library/Application\: No such file or directory`

I've tried different combos of single and double quotes -- to no avail.
Please advice, thank  you in advance.

### EDIT 1

I've tried writing the pathfile in .bash_profile within backticks. After *sourcing* it, I immediate get back `-bash: /Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Anki2/me/collection.media: is a directory`

### EDIT 2

For future reference, I created a link in the home directory of the User and pointed it to the `collection.media` folder. This just a workaround, I would greatly appreciate it if someone helped me solve this puzzle.

Comment: Have you tried "triple backslash followed by one space" too?

Comment: Same problem. Gives `-bash: cd: /Users/<username>/Library/Application\: No such file or directory` (this time no quotes at all, just triple backslash after `Application`)

Comment: I wonder if triple backslash with no quotes is equivalent to single backslash with double quotes which you had tried already.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The shell uses a space character as a separator between words, so paths containing spaces always must be put in `""` when used (which implies that it is recommended/best practice to ensure that all paths and file names in shell scripts and init files are properly quoted):

```
ANKI_MEDIA="/Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Anki2/me/collection.media"
cd "$ANKI_MEDIA"
```

You can also use `\` to protect a space but this only works for literal paths, not for variables:

```
cd /Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Anki2/me/collection.media
```

If applying quotes each time you change into this directory is inconvenient you can use an alias instead:

```
alias cdanki="cd '$ANKI_MEDIA'"
```

Comment: Tried `cd "$ANKI_MEDIA"`, didn't work! Do I need to put the same line in a file titled `.bashrc`?

Comment: Just issuing `echo $ANKI_MEDIA` is fine, the part of the pathfile that contains problematic space character is printed on screen without any distortion. It's the `cd` command that gives problems. Why? Keeps saying that `Application` is not a file or folder.

Comment: found a workaround, see OP Edit 2

Comment: @WobblyWindows "didn't work" is a bit broad, how exactly does it fail? I've edited the question and added some explanation why paths with spaces cause problems

Comment: "didn't work" means that after I source the `.bash_profile` file, then 'cd' to environment variable path as indicated above, bash responds _No such file or directory_

Comment: @wobblywindows what was the value of $ANKI_MEDIA at that moment? And you did run `cd "$ANKI_MEDIA"`, including the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake on the pathfile name (after Anki2/me/...) : the user profile was actually "me_201908". Also, this time around I edited the file in vim and used $HOME in the variable's pathfile.